# Создать файл PDF

Tags: c#, файлы, pdf

Есть программа на WinForms которая в числе прочего формирует небольшой отчет в txt формате. С этим все просто, но возникла необходимость сохранять еще и картинку. Вопрос : можно ли силами c# создать pdf с текстом и изображением, если да то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы писать  через itextsharp в созданном PDF на русском можно сделать так :

```
            var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20,20,30,20);

            string ttf = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ARIALNBI.TTF");
            var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(ttf, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            var font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(baseFont, iTextSharp.text.Font.DEFAULTSIZE, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);


            using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)))
            {
              document.Open();
              document.NewPage();
              document.Add(new Paragraph("Русский текст",font));
              document.Close();
              writer.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

[itextsharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

```
var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
```

Создание документа

```
using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("result.pdf", FileMode.Create)))
{
    document.Open();

    // do some work here

    document.Close();
    writer.Close();
}
```

Рисование линий

```
writer.DirectContent.MoveTo(35, 780);
writer.DirectContent.LineTo(430, 780);
```

Добавление картинки

```
var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(new FileStream(@"Resources\logo.jpg", FileMode.Open));
logo.SetAbsolutePosition(440, 758);
writer.DirectContent.AddImage(logo);
```

Добавление текста

```
helvetica = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12);
helveticaBase = helvetica.GetCalculatedBaseFont(false);
writer.DirectContent.BeginText();
writer.DirectContent.SetFontAndSize(helveticaBase, 12f);
writer.DirectContent.ShowTextAligned(iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "Hello world!", 35, 766, 0);
writer.DirectContent.EndText();
```

С помощью других библиотек (iTextSharp Report.NET PDFsharp SharpPDF PDFjet ASP.NET FO PDF PDF Clown) описано здесь

https://habrahabr.ru/post/112707/

Comment: Не отображаются русские буквы. что с этим можно сделать ?